# How do process video frames at a constant frame rate?

Tags: python, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to process a video and convert the video to greyscale and do some pixel manipulations on each frame of the video in real time as it's being processed and displayed on screen using imshow() with OpenCV. The problem I'm running into is that each frame takes a different amount of time to process and the frame rate isn't constant, as the video appears to lag at random times as it's being processed and displayed. So the processed video does not actually process and play in real time. I want it to display the processed video as it's being processed without any lag time, so that it appears to be a real time video rather than juttery in random spots as the lag time from the video processing computations makes it less than ideal.

I have some debugging in there to show time per frame it takes:

```
Time this frame: 0.015553
Time this frame: 0.015620
Time this frame: 0.015673
Time this frame: 0.031236
Time this frame: 0.031249
Time this frame: 0.031237
Time this frame: 0.031247
Time this frame: 0.031283
Time this frame: 0.031265
Time this frame: 0.015629
Time this frame: 0.015502
```

It's pretty basic code.

```
//capture the video file
//get each frame
//while capture is opened
//convert each frame to greyscale and do some minor video processing code
//cv2.imshow("window", VideoInGreyscale)
//repeat until video file is completely processed and video ends
```

As you can see, it is inconsistent. I want each time this frame to be exactly the same as the video is being processed. It doesn't have to be as fast as possible, consistency for each frame is more important than fastest video processing time. I am processing 1205 frames in 20 seconds, but the frames not consistently timed so it appears laggy in the video

Answer (score 1):

In video game programing we have this technique to lock frame rates

```
import time

processing = True
frames_per_second = 2
time_in_frame = (1 / frames_per_second) * 1000 #milliseconds

def get_cur_millis():
   return int(round(time.time() * 1000))

def process():
   print("processing...")

while processing:
   start_time = get_cur_millis()
   print("current time is {}".format(get_cur_millis()))
   process()
   time_elapsed = get_cur_millis() - start_time
   # Sleep until till the next frame should run.
   time.sleep(max((time_in_frame - time_elapsed) / 1000, 0))
```

When I run it, the output is:

```
current time is 1565329457172
processing...
current time is 1565329457675
processing...
current time is 1565329458176
processing...
current time is 1565329458678
processing...
current time is 1565329459179
processing...
current time is 1565329459681
processing...
current time is 1565329460181
processing...
```

You can see that the time difference between each processing is 500ms (2 FPS). You can bump up the FPS to whatever you like but if your processing time is longer than a frame (1/FPS seconds). This code will still cause lag.